# Multitude of problems with 2014 Mac Mini

Tags: macos, hardware, mac-mini

A family member’s 2014 Mac Mini has had a whole host of problems, for the last three weeks or so (we think).

**Problems found and noted**

- running and responding slowly
- booting and shutting down very slowly (~4 minutes)
- occasionally dumping users out to the login screen with no warning or explanation
- frequently failing to fully launch apps
- almost always failing to respond in a user-perceivable way when links are left (primary button) clicked in Safari
- failing to backup to Time Machine
- failing to sync iCloud keychain data
- refusing to connect to Wi-Fi if certain (currently unknown) USB peripheral(s) other than keyboard and mouse are connected
- if USB mouse is unplugged while the machine is on, it will not work on reconnecting it
- usually drops HDMI connection to monitor for five seconds or so on waking

**Troubleshooting steps tried**

- ran Apple Diagnostics - *passed*
- SMART tests and First Aid file system checks on startup disk - *all passed*
- rebuilt Spotlight index
- made a test user account to verify the issues aren’t related to a specific user account
- reset local keychain
- deleted some remnants of long-uninstalled software from various library folders
- checked Console for obvious tell-tale errors (admittedly I have little knowledge of Console so wouldn’t necessarily notice relevant errors)
- booted in Safe mode - *problems persisted*
- reset PRAM, even though I can’t see how it could cause any of the above problems

Next time I have access to the machine (Friday 9 July) I plan to find out which USB peripheral(s) affect the WiFi, and reinstall Catalina.

Is this likely to be a logic board problem? And if so, could that have been caused by a bad peripheral (suspecting a cheap two-drive hard disk caddy which I use for the TM drives)? If not a logic board problem or perhaps due to multiple issues, what else could cause all or most of these errors?

Comment: ....maybe. I would back up the system, reformat the drive and then re-install the operating system. Only restore apps ad backup files once you have verified the issues are gone or not.

Comment: Thanks, that’s a good suggestion which hadn’t ocurred to me. I’ll give it a try next weekend.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the SMC (or whatever it is called, the configuration-in-non-volatile-ram thing)?

Comment: The HD might the source of the bottleneck, especially if it is the base model without an SSD and/or Fusion drive. Options for this model: 500 GB or 1 TB (5400-rpm) hard drive, configurable to 256, 512 GB or 1 TB flash storage or 1 or 2 TB Fusion Drive.

Comment: Haven’t tried resetting the SMC, will give it a go.

Comment: I agree the HD, which I think is the 1TB 5,400 rpm drive, could be *a* bottleneck but I don’t see how it could be the cause of many of these problems, as most or all of them are very recent and the HD passes SMART and First Aid tests.

Comment: I have reset the PRAM however, will add that to the question.

Comment: Update your question with the report results from EtreCheck which will not publish personal information. But it can let us know if you have any malware / adware installed or other weird things going on.  https://etrecheck.com (free version is fine)

Comment: Looks like the HD is showing it’s age. I’d consider replacing it with an SSD or hybrid drive at least. I’ve done this twice for a 2012 model (with a clean OS install) and each time the difference is inreal.